# Where to download GASPER

Tags: bytecode

Where can I find and download GASPER (short for GAS-costly Patterns checkER), the tool mentioned in the paper [Under-Optimized Smart Contracts
Devour Your Money](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03994.pdf)?

Comment: Note that this paper was published in March 2017, but written in November 2016. The compiler has undergone lots of work since then, including, most probably, improvements on the things the paper was complaining about.

Answer (score 4):

You could try emailing the authors of the publication and authors of the code.

The publication contains the contact details for the author of the code and paper.

```
Email: brokendragon@uestc.edu.cn, {csxqli,csxluo}@comp.polyu.edu.hk, johnsonzxs@uestc.edu.cn
```

Most likely they have not published it anywhere publicly yet.  When you get a response from them, do come back and update the question with extra info.